# CollapsingToolbarLayout cannot expand when RecyclerView scroll down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I try CollapsingToolbarLayout on my App where RecyclerView in Fragment. Toolbar can colapse whe scrollUp but cannot expand when scroll down RecyclerView  ,
this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/vUserProfileRoot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                android:paddingLeft="24dp"
                android:paddingRight="24dp"
                android:paddingTop="64dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clipChildren="false">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivUserProfilePhoto"
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/vUserDetails"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="John Smith"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="24sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="\@jsmith"
                            android:textColor="#bbbbbb"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Mobile development passionate."
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnFollow"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:text="following"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/vUserStats"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="1167"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="posts"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="396"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="followers"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="485"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="following"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_outline_white_24dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.ScrollingFABBehavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}
```

this is the result >> [My App (video)](https://vid.me/i8Hv)
so how to fix it ?

Comment: Let me know your support recyclerview version ?

Comment: 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1' sir